# First reference to the Tits alternative

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory

As we know, the "Tits alternative" is a theorem relating to finitely generated linear groups.

I was curious as to where in the literature the Tits alternative is first referred to by this name, as I believe it is never refereed to as the "alternative" in the [original 1972 paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82779690.pdf) '*Free Subgroups in Linear Groups*' by Jacques Tits and is simply stated as a theorem.

Comment: A straightforward search on Google scholar yields a 1976 paper by Roman'kov (English traduction of Russian 1976 paper): https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01876320?LI=true.